# how to generate this layout in java swing

Tags: java, swing

I am wondering if anyone can help me with the generation of this layout:

[image]

I have wasted a lot of time.

What I want is:

1) The sizes of jButton1, jLabel1 and jLabel2 are the same as their original ones on resizing.

2) The sizes of jTextField1 and jTextField2 will automatically expand on resizing, but the total width of jTextField1+jLabel1 is the same as jTextField2+jLabel2.

3) The heights of JTree1 and JTree2 will automatically expand on resizing, and their widths are the same. They need to be placed in a JScrollPane so that there will be scrollbars when the trees get expanded.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could use netbeans for creating this directly

Comment: @Suhail Gupta: -1  Netbeans in the hands of someone who does not understand layouts, tends to produce fragile, unmaintainable code.  Bad idea!

Answer (score 2):

It may take some experimentation..  I would start with a BorderLayout with "Top" and "Center"

"Top" only contains the button (You may need to find a container that makes it do what you want--you have to find something that presses it out to the right size).  Center contains the rest.

In center you place something that divides evenly, I think a horizontal flow layout will do that.  Might also use a splitter to drag the sizes if you want.

In each of the two sides of the flow layout (or whichever works). you add a BorderLayout with the label and text at the "top" and the "center" being left for the tree.

For the label and text field you might want to use ANOTHER BorderLayout and specify west for the button and center for the field.

Your components should then resize the way you want.

In summary, perhaps something like:

```
BorderLayout
    top:
        BorderLayout
            bottom:
                button (May need to be in another container to get the size right)

    center:
        Split pane or flow layout
            left side (Same as right side):
                BorderLayout 
                    top:
                        BorderLayout
                            west:
                                label
                            center:
                                textbox
                    center:
                        JTree
```

Comment: could you give some code snippet for such a design? I still cannot get it to work.

Comment: Why don't you show us what you have so far and we'll help you figure out why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Look here:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

I would personally wrap the whole thing in a [GridBagLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for the flexibility it offers. Beyond that I often find it easier to put stuff inside [GridLayouts](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) or [BoxLayouts](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) and then put those in the [GridBagLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) so that I don't have to deal with specific weights for every object.

Comment: could you give some code snippet for such a design? I still cannot get it to work.